# Why do I need to source bash_profile every time

Tags: hadoop, bash

I have installed Hadoop and every time I want to run it, first I have to do this:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or it won't recognize the command `hadoop`

Why is that?

I am on OSX 10.8

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your `.bash_profile`? Do you have a `.bashrc`?

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret : Thanks, yes I have both. Posted them in here: https://gist.github.com/babakinks/5281748

Comment: If you add an `echo "Hello, World!"` towards the end of `.bash_profile`, do you see that it gets executed when you open a terminal?

Comment: Are you even using BASH? Try "chsh" if not.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret : I added your echo command to the end of that bash_profile, quit my iTerm2 terminal..opened it again..so I should see a hello world message?  I did NOT see that.

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret : I also have a .zshrc for z-shell... I added a echo to that one... and it shows the message from that one.

Comment: ... which obviously means you should add all the lines from 6 to 13 to your `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Now that we've narrowed down the problem:

1. Run `ps -p $$` at the command line to check if you are, in fact, using a bash shell.
2. Realize that you are in zsh, which means you should be editing your profile in `.zshrc`.
3. Copy the offending lines from `.bash_profile` to `.zshrc`, OR
4. <strike>Modify your `.zshrc` to directly source your `.bash_profile`.</strike>

UPDATE: Do what @TC1 mentions in the comments and keep the shell-specific code in each shell's own profile, and from those profiles, only source shell-agnostic code.

Comment: Well a blatantly obvious reason **not** to source a **Bash specific** configuration file from Z shell would be the possibility for it to contain **Bash specific** configuration... Copying the lines over or externalizing them to some `PATH` setup file & sourcing from both would be appropriate.

Comment: @TC1 Yes, that is the type of reason I was referring to. :) So keep it clean and do what TC1 says.

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen in all my years as an engineer. Correct, made me laugh and still was polite. Fixed my problem and made my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

On Mac Catalina, I just had to open "preferences" on terminal and change the "shells open with" from "default" to "Command(complete path)", which the default path was "/bin/zsh". `touch ~/.zshrc`, if that file doesn't exist already, and copy/paste your stuff from ".bash_profile" into the ".zshrc" file.

To elaborate, with terminal running, I opened "settings" from the Terminal menu on the Mac navbar. On the "General" tab, look for "Shells open with" select "Command (complete path)", and type in `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: LOL I was using zsh this whole time because I guess my company laptop came with it set that way. Thanks!

Comment: Since this was what worked for me i would like a little more verbose if possible, since i couldn't understand half of it. Just went ahead with the creation of .zshrc and copy the stuff.  How did you opened preferences from terminal? How did you change the opening option?

Comment: @Mbotet, I updated it with more instructions. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

`bash_profile.sh` is applicable for `bash` shell.
if your default shell is not `bash` and if your default shell is someother shell for example `zsh` then you have to manually load the `.bash_profile` using `source ~/.bash_profile`.

You can always change the default shell to `bash` shell so that the `.bash_profile` file will be automatically loaded.

Inorder to automatically load `.bash_profile`, you can update your default shell to `bash` using the command `chsh -s /bin/bash`

> `cat /etc/shells` will list the default shells available in the
> machine

[image]

> `echo $SHELL` will display the currently active shell in your machine

[image]

> To change active shell to a different shell, use `chsh -s /bin/bash`.
> Then `echo $SHELL` to verify if the shell has changed.

Comment: you need to restart the shell after adding any change to see it effective.

Answer (score 14):

Terminal -> Preference -> profile -> Shell -> Run command : source ~/.bash_profile

Tick on run inside shell.

After doing all those , just logout and check weather everything works fine or not

Answer (score 1):

I tried the approved answer. Changing the .zshrc file works for one of my machines. But for the other one, when I run ps -p $$, it is -sh under the command. And I changed both bash and zsh files, neither of them works for me this time.

So I found this 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

it mentioned
"When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. "

so I went to that file /etc/profile and add "source ~/.bashrc" in that file. Then it works since every time a terminal is opened, it runs the command in that /etc/profile file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution but it works.

`sudo nano /etc/bashrc` and change that, restarted the terminal and it finally remembered with command. Tried `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` without success, just wasn't sourcing it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to “Preferences/Profiles then look in the right window and find “shell”.

Once in that if your “Startup Run Command” hasn’t been turned on. Click the box to turn it on and in the command section type:

(If you made a `.zsh` file)

```sh
source .zsh ; clear
```

(If you made a `.bash_profile`)

```sh
source .bash_profile ; clear
```

Doing this `; clear`

Will clear your terminal to a new page so that you don’t see your terminal display:

```
“Last login: etc 
User@user-Mac ~ % source .zsh
```

If you typed the commands as I said you should just get this:

```
User@user-Mac ~ %
```

That way you will be greeted with a clear page with no extra jumbo. Also to make sure that your `.zsh` or `.bash_profile` aliases work type the following command to see a list of your custom aliases:

```
Alias
```

One alias I like to do is

```sh
alias LL=“ls -la”
```

This will display a tree or the directory you are in as well as hidden files.

Answer (score -1):

**Issue Description:**
Every time I open a new terminal window, Flutter commands are not recognized until I manually run  `source ~/.bash_profile`

I am facing the issue of having to manually run `source ~/.bash_profile` on every new terminal window startup to set up their Flutter environment on macOS, here's a helpful solution:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Navigate to "Preferences."
3. Under the "Profiles" tab, select your preferred profile (usually labeled
   "Default" or your chosen profile).
4. In the "Shell" tab, check the "Run command" box.
5. Enter the command `source ~/.bash_profile`

[image]