# Why is there a need to do source ~/.bash_profile after booting into the computer?

Tags: linux, octopress, bash

I have installed octopress but to make it run (just after booting computer up) I need to do every time :

```
    source ~/.bash_profile
```

unless I do this I get an error when I run:

```
    rake generate
```

Error:

```
    bash: /usr/local/bin/rake: /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have Ubuntu 12.0 LTS and I've gone through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733508/why-do-i-need-to-source-bash-profile-every-time)  , but since am unaware of the basics of shell profiles and shell I couldn't understand the answer. Please enlighten me on that too.

The only solution on my mind seems to have a cron job scheduled for reboot so every time I reboot, it does a source ~/.bash_profile. Please suggest if there is any other solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's ~/.bash_profile? Because in your text you wrote ~/bash_profile (without the dot.)

Comment: Is your default shell bash?

Comment: @Jeremy: 12.04. defaults to bash (aliased as sh).

Comment: @NikosC. Oh sorry ,minor error. Yes Its the ~/.bash_profile

Comment: How did you install octopress? I'm not familiar with it. Did the install instructions of ocropress tell you to add something to .bash_profile?

Comment: Yes in the end of installing ruby there was a instruction which asked me to do source ~/.bash_profile    Check these out : http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rbenv/

Comment: @Jeremy Yes my default shell is bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of configuration files the shell may execute when you invoke it. By and large, they contain aliases (alternative names for commands), path-adjustments, and variable initializations; in your case, it alerts the shell to the location of a command (program) which it otherwise would not find in the PATH environmental variable.

The .bash_profile one is invoked when you start a login shell, which you probably don't. Go into your home directory (cd ~), type ls -la, and you should see a .bashrc config file. That one is invoked when you start a shell. Try opening it with your text editor of choice, and add the command you type in as the last line of the .bashrc file. This should allow you to no longer have to enter the command interactively, as it will be invoked when you start a shell.

Comment: That won't work, since .bash_profile sources .bashrc. If you now source .bash_profile from .bashrc, you get an infinite recursion and this will hang your login and crash when stack space is exhausted.

Comment: It is working pretty good for now. Thank you! It isn't hanging.

Comment: @Nikos C.: When you start a shell with ctrl-alt-t (or from the menu), .bashrc is called, not .bash_login (called for login shells). So it doesn't help here that .bash_login sources .bashrc.

Comment: I thought that your answer was telling the OP to source .bash_profile from within .bashrc...